# Fluent Repository/QueryBuilder

Tags: c#, repository, fluent-interface

I've been toying around making my repositories a bit more fluent for a while. I was ending up with crazy long method names when I had to query on multiple conditions. So I've been working on a way to query fluently.

**Usage**

**Insert/Update/Delete**

Looks and behaves exactly like a normal repository.

```
var personRepository = new PersonRepository(dbContext);

personRepository.Insert(new Person {...});
personRepository.Update(person);
personRepository.Remove(person);
```

**Querying**

Allows you to call any query methods, narrowing down the query more and more as you go and can execute the query synchronously or asynchronously.

```
var person = await personRepository.Query()
    .ByFirstName("neil")
    .ByLastName("smith")
    .Include(m => m.Addresses)
    .OrderBy(m => m.LastName)
    .Take(5)
    .ToEntitiesAsync();

var person = personRepository.Query()
    .ById(99)
    .ToEntity();

var person = await personRepository.Query()
    .WhereFirstNameContains("jr")
    .ToEntitiesAsync();
```

So the code behind this:

**Entity Base Class**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository Contracts**

```
public interface IPersistableRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
}

public interface IQueryableRepository<TEntity, out TQueryBuilder>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
    where TQueryBuilder : class, IQueryBuilder<TEntity, TQueryBuilder>    
{
    TQueryBuilder Query();
}

public interface IQueryBuilder<TEntity, out TQueryBuilder>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
    where TQueryBuilder : class
{
    TQueryBuilder ById(int id);
    ...

    TQueryBuilder Include<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> prop);
    TQueryBuilder OrderBy<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> prop);
    TQueryBuilder OrderByDescending<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> prop);
    TQueryBuilder Take(int count);
    TQueryBuilder After(int id);
    TQueryBuilder Before(int id);

    TEntity ToEntity();
    Task<TEntity> ToEntityAsync();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> ToEntities();
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ToEntitiesAsync();
}
```

**Repository Base Classes**

```
public abstract class PersistableRepository<TEntity> : IPersistableRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;

    protected PersistableRepository(IDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet { 
        get { return _context.Set<TEntity>(); }
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity) {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity) {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity) {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}

public abstract class QueryBuilder<TEntity, TQueryBuilder> 
    : IQueryBuilder<TEntity, TQueryBuilder>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
    where TQueryBuilder : class
{
    protected QueryBuilder(IQueryable<TEntity> query) {
        Query = query;
    }

    protected IQueryable<TEntity> Query { get; set; }

    public TQueryBuilder ById(int id) {
        Query = Query.Where(m => m.Id == id);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TQueryBuilder Include<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> prop) {
        Query = Query.Include(prop);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TQueryBuilder OrderBy<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> prop) {
        Query = Query.OrderBy(prop);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TQueryBuilder OrderByDescending<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> prop) {
        Query = Query.OrderByDescending(prop);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TQueryBuilder Take(int count) {
        Query = Query.Take(count);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TQueryBuilder After(int id) {
        Query = Query.Where(m => m.Id >= id);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TQueryBuilder Before(int id) {
        Query = Query.Where(m => m.Id <= id);
        return this as TQueryBuilder;
    }

    public TEntity ToEntity() {
        return Query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> ToEntityAsync() {
        return await Query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> ToEntities() {
        return Query.ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ToEntitiesAsync() {
        return await Query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**Repository & QueryBuilder Interfaces**

```
public interface IPersonRepository
    : IPersistableRepository<Person>, IQueryableRepository<Person, IPersonQueryBuilder>
{
}

public interface IPersonQueryBuilder
    : IQueryBuilder<Person, IPersonQueryBuilder>
{
    IPersonQueryBuilder ByFirstName(string firstName);
    IPersonQueryBuilder ByLastName(string lastName);
    IPersonQueryBuilder ByAge(int age);
    IPersonQueryBuilder WhereFirstNameContains(string val);
    ...
}
```

**Repository Implementation**

```
public class PersonRepository : PersistableRepository<Cohort>, IPersonRepository
{
    public PersonRepository(IDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IPersonQueryBuilder Query() {
        return new PersonQueryBuilder(DbSet.AsQueryable());
    }
}

public class PersonQueryBuilder
    : QueryBuilder<Person, IPersonQueryBuilder>, IPersonQueryBuilder
{
    public PersonQueryBuilder(IQueryable<Person> query) : base(query)
    {
    }

    public IPersonQueryBuilder ByFirstName(string firstName) {
        Query = Query.Where(m => m.FirstName == firstName);
        return this;
    }

    public IPersonQueryBuilder ByLastName(string lastName) {
        Query = Query.Where(m => m.LastName == lastName);
        return this;
    }

    public IPersonQueryBuilder ByAge(int age) {
        Query = Query.Where(m => m.Age == age);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Everything has it's place. Query methods shared by all entity classes belong to the abstract `QueryBuilder`. Methods used to persist data belong to the abstract `PerstiableRepository`. All Repository and QueryBuilder methods are enforced by an interface so it's inject-able and testable. And the ability to use whatever combination of query methods give it a better query syntax I believe. Each repository can implement either `IPersistableRepository`, `IQueryableRepository`, or both.

But I'm not an expert. Am I missing anything? Should I not do this this way? You tell me what's wrong with my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quite like the concept.  The only thing that stands out for me initially is that I would probably leave the wrapping methods the same as their wrapped name.

i.e.

```
TEntity FirstOrDefault()
Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync()
IEnumerable<TEntity> All()
Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> AsEnumerable();
```

rather than

```
TEntity ToEntity();
Task<TEntity> ToEntityAsync();
IEnumerable<TEntity> ToEntities();
Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ToEntitiesAsync();
```

I guess my main reasoning is that `FirstOrDefault` makes it clear what we are retrieving where as `ToEntity()` leaves it open to thought between `Single()` and `First()`.

Neat idea thought.  Be interested to see what others think.

Comment: Can't imagine why I decided to change those method names. Makes a lot of sense to keep in consistent and will make a lot more sense if I want to add `Find`, `Single`, etc... Thanks for the input. Going to edit my question with this change in a few.